How to page through Microsoft graph change notification subscriptions?
I've created 22 subscriptions in the graph API via POST /subscription endpoint. When I fetch the full list of subscriptions (GET /subscriptions), I receive a page of 20 subscriptions and a @odata.nextLink. Fetching the next link returns the same exact 20 subscriptions. It too has a nextLink and that nextLink returns the same 20 subscriptions, and so on. Has anyone had similar experience? How can I page through my subscriptions or query them by certain fields other than the subscription ID?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?tabs=http

@DileepaMabulage Yes, I've read that, but as I mentioned, the nextLink returns the same 20 subscriptions, it's returning the first page for every nextLink.

Can you try with the custom pagination top=<top count>&skip=<skip count>
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions?$top=22
source

I've tried this with different combinations of top and skip, every request returns the same 20 results from the first page.

Can you check adding the $count=true whether there are more than 20

Settings $count=true, like this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions?$count=true did not add a count to the output or change the output json in any way.

Sorry, I'm out of ideas brother, It's better to put this in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/
